# Using Spring Data JPA, how can I create a query with multiple conditions ORed on same field?

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa, jpql

I need help creating a JPQL query out of a native query having or condition along with other fields. Please lemme know if it is still not supported by JPA.

Sample Native Query :

```
select * from EMP where (EMP_FLAG is NULL or EMP_FLAG is 'Y') and EMP_ID in (1,2,3);
```

Now to use JPQL (Java Persistent Query Language) I have written following in-build query using source

```
findByEmpIdInAndEmpFlagIsNotNull(List<Long> ids);
```

But how to incorporate the check for EMP_FLAG = 'Y'?

> Note** I do not intend to add a query using @Query annotation. (aware
>   of that solution)

Spring version : 4.2,
JAVA : 1.7

Comment: Please advice if it is impossible to use in-build query in this particular scenario.. I am not looking for only automatic query, I want to understand the possibilities that JPQL has provided us with.

Answer (score 4):

You can do like this

```
@Query("select e from EMP e where (e.empFlag is null of e.empFlag ='Y')and in :ids")
findByEmpIdIn(@Param("ids") List<Long> ids);
```

Comment: Hi Suresh, I have a similar question.  I'd like to implement a query like this "select e.* from emp e where (timestamp > e.startDate and timestamp <e.endDate) or (timestamp > e.startDate and e.endDate is null) ", how can I write the HQL?

Answer (score 1):

Choose the name you find the best for your method, and annotate it with

```
@Query("select e from Employee e where (e.empFlag is null of e.empFlag = 'Y') and e.empId in ?1")
```

Comment: I am aware of this solution but I was willing to use something similar to findBy where I dont have to write @Query thing.

Comment: automatic queries generated by method names should not be abused. They're handy for simple things like findByName(), but for things like what you have, they're harder to write than simply writing the query by yourself, they cause horribly long and cryptic method names, and these method names must be changed as soon as the actual criteria change (like, for example, if you start using boolean fields instead of Y/N).

Comment: I agree with the suggestion that the method names should be changed. But what is wrong in using automatic queries? There are several advantages to it. The code rather looks more crispier and there are no chances of failures even if some DB configs change in the back end.  And if it is a boolean field, anyways things will change in Native query as well so the effort to make changes in the code remains equal if not less.

Comment: @Dish not sure I understand. If you name your method "findActiveEmployees()" and annotate it with `@Query`, changing the way youdeal with flags will only change the value of the Query annotation. The method name, and all the places where this method is called, won't have to change at all. This is much better than "findByEmpFlagEqualsYAndEmpIdIn", which is an awful name, and has to be changed to "findByEmpFlagEqualsTrueAndEmpIdIn" when you decide to use a boolean rather than a string for the flag. That's all I mean by my previous comment.

Comment: Ok, I think this is (findByEmpFlagEqualsTrueAndEmpIdIn) possible if the flag is boolean and not String.